# Java StringBuilder ## issue

Tags: java, string

In my application I'm preparing a user logs list in the way as below:

```
final StringBuilder _sb = new StringBuilder();
final String[] _ae = _d.getErrorsDetails();

for (int i=0; i<_ae.length; ++i) {
    _sb.append(_ae[i]);                    
    _sb.append(i == _ae.length-1 ? "" : s+s);
}
```

The `s` variable is a `#` character. When I append two `s` variables one after one and then when I call `toString()` method on `_sb` I get `#70` against `##`. Would you tell me why?

Comment: Use a Debugger and you will find it out

Comment: I've tried but everything seems correct until I call _sb.toString()...

Comment: Might be easier just to put `_sb.append(s+s);` (or whatever fixes the bug) after the for loop. No need to keep checking `i == _ae.length-1`.

Comment: @AndyTurner the condition's the other way around - don't append if at last element.

Comment: @JiriTousek ah! Then still, you don't need the condition: just go up to `_ae.length-1` in the loop, and append the last element outside.

Comment: @AndyTurner Sure, if the code in the cycle is simple enough not to constitute a violation of "Don't Repeat Yourself" principle.

Answer (score 3):

if `s` is `char` and not `String`, `s + s` will perform integer addition (i.e. add the characters' code point value) instead of string concatenation.

Comment: Thanks, now I undersrtand.

Comment: No, I'm still not sure. Earlier I've changed a bit my code and create new string variable where I put ## at its end. Then I've append this string to _sb and in result I get also #70 against ##.

Comment: Then please post a [mcve] showing that. Otherwise we can only guess where you made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

35 is integer for # and 35 + 35 is 70 and it looks like ae[i] is #

Comment: No ae[i] is a string-text value different than #